# How to publish my website on internet in windows iis server use my personal computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, iis-7

I coded a website with asp.net and I want to publish my web site on internet in my PC, I don't have a static ip adress.

Is it possible? If it is possible, how? I'm running Windows7, IIS7, and asp.net

Comment: Offtopic here. It is definitely possible, but I'd not recommend doing so based on the fact you need to ask this question - your home network is unlikely to be safely configured to take hostile traffic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the following tutorial can help you http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1247-how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis.aspx

Answer (score 3):

First of all: This is not a programming question.

Now to your question:

It is possible to host a website behind a "home router" with changing IP addresses. You simply need a [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)(for example [DynDNS](http://dyndns.org)) solution to get a static domain address for your host (IP).

**But** I wouldn't recommend it. There are many potential risks which you have to take care of when hosting a homepage on your private network (Hackers, (D)[DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), ...). In case something happens, it *will* affect your **private** home network.

Furthermore your network bandwidth might not be fast enough (regarding the upload speed) to handle outgoing traffic.

I'd suggest you rent a webspace for about 5$/month including an static-address and/or domain or a V-Server if you want to use ASP.Net.

Update 2017:
You can use the [Mono-Project for Linux to run ASP.Net Pages (up to .Net 2.0)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/), which is a port of the .NET framework. 
Additionally I recommend the newly created [ASP.Net Core](https://www.asp.net/core) which is supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dns service that allows a dynamic ip. I guess [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) can help you.

Comment: we dont use domain name, we can use ip adress 5 person use this site

Comment: Is it an internal or public site?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if your computer is always on and your internet connection is always on.

For dns, use a service like no-ip.org to get a dns name for your dynamic ip.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a dynamic DNS. http://www.dyndns.com (Recommended)

Then download their client to your server and run it.

The DYNUpdater will associate your dynamic IP with the DNS.

After that, open port 80 on your router and forward it to your server. Static IP on the server is preferred.

Last thing, navigate to the dynamic DNS you created earlier and you will have access to the server.